# Error while installing Microsoft.net and NuGet latest version from visual studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

An error is occuring while I always try to install Microsoft.net latest version. The error shown is -
"The latest version you want to install is incompatible with your NuGet version. So first update your NuGet"

Now how to install NuGet latest version from visual studio is a challenge.

Can anybody pls help on this ?

Comment: What the version of your Visual Studio and NuGet version? How did you install the Microsoft.net? using NuGet Package Manager? but I did not find a package of "Microsoft.net", is that custom package?

Comment: Visual studio version that I am using is 2012. I tried installing latest version of  .net from Extensions in tools of visual studio. I have NuGet v2.0 installed. I want to Update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

> how to install NuGet latest version from visual studio is a challenge

If want to install NuGet latest version from Visual Studio, you can update the NuGet by the **Extensions and Updates...**, find the tool of NuGet Package Manager For Visual Studio, then update it.

[image]

Note: If you are using Visual Studio 2015, there is a [NuGet beta channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget#nuget-cli), the NuGet Beta Channel for the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015 gives you access to high-quality builds that are close to completion.

Besides, you can also update the NuGet by installing the high version [NuGet VSIX](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html), pay attention to restart Visual Studio after installation.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried doing it the same. But then I get an error - " your system is low in memory. Visual studio is closing some files to free up memory". I click Ok. And then nothing happens..

Comment: That is because your memory is very low, you can close some of the processes you do not use or improve your computer's configuration., then try to update again.